# Entity Framework 4 Linq help - Pulling data from multiple tables filtered

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Not sure how this is done, I have my .edmx set up so that the navigation properties match the foreign key relationships on the tables. Not sure if I still need to perform joins or if EF will give me access to the related table data through the navigational properties automatically.

[image]

What I need to do it get all the ContentSections and their associated ContentItems based on the ContentView and filtered by the DiversionProgram.CrimeNumber.

I would like to get back IEnumerable, for each ContentSection it should have access to it's ContentItems via the navigation property ContentItems

Thanks

Comment: Are you setting up a criminal network? Can I Join? ;)

Comment: Sure it's easy to join... just find your local cop and give him a big slap in the face and you will instantly be part of the network! LOL

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
using(Entities context = new Entities())
{
  IEnumerable<ContentSection> enumerator = context.ContentSections
  .Include("ContentItems")
  .Where<ContentSection>(cs => cs.ContentView.ContentViewID == someID && cs.ContentItems.Where<ContentItem>(ci => ci.DiversionProgram.CrimeNumber == someCrimeNumber))
  .AsEnumerable<ContentSection>
}
```

I've interpreted

> based on the ContentView

as `cs.ContentView.ContentViewID == someID`

This will give you all the ContentSections for a given ContentView. And interpreted

> filtered by the DiversionProgram.CrimeNumber

as `cs.ContentItems.Where<ContentItem>(ci => ci.DiversionProgram.CrimeNumber == someCrimeNumber)`

which will give you all those ContentItems that have a specific CrimeNumber.

Or did you mean something else with based on / filtered by. Maybe OrderBy, or all those ContentSections where Any of it's ContentItems would have a certain CrimeNumber?

Comment: getting error cannot apply operator '&&' to operands of type bool and IEnumerable when using your example.

Comment: I See. If you use Any instead of Where you will have more chance. But then the outcome will be different. But try and see if it meets your needs. If not, come back here and we'll think about it further.

Answer (score 0):

You can eager load to get *all* associated records, but when you want to start filtering/ordering, don't bother with `Include`.

Just do a projection with anonymous types and EF will work out what it needs to do. It's a bit hairy, but it'll work. If it get's too complicated, bite the bullet and use a SPROC.

Now, with that caveat, something like this (off the top of my head):

```
var query = ctx.ContentView
               .Select(x => new 
{
   ContentSections = x.ContentSections
                      .Where(y => y.ContentItems
                        .Any(z => z.DivisionProgram.CrimeNumber = 87))
}).ToList().Select(x => x.ContentSections);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the CTP5 you can do something very unique it looks like this:

```
var context = new YourEntitiesContext();

var query = context.ContentView.Include(cs => cs.ContentSections
                   .Select(ci => ci.ContentItems
                   .Select(dp => dp.DiversionProgram)
                   .Where(dp.CrimeNumber == crimeNumber)))
                   .Where(cv => cv.ContentViewID == contentViewID).FirtsOrDefault();
```

You can learn more about the CTP5 and how it can be used in Database first scenario [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/14/ef-feature-ctp5-model-amp-database-first-with-dbcontext.aspx)

Comment: how is that unique to CTP5? That's basic LINQ-Entities. And the include is unnecessary when your projecting.

Comment: ...Yes it is you can't use typed Include in LINQ to Entities prior to EF4 CTP5.

Comment: ahh right. I was confused since you didn't specify which part of the code was "unique". my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
 var query = from t1 in studentManagementEntities.StudentRegistrations
                        join t2 in studentManagementEntities.StudentMarks
                        on t1.StudentID equals t2.StudentID
                        select new
                        {
                            t1.selected column name,
                            t2.selected column name
                        };
```